# Anyone can help me Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' null object

Tags: android-studio

**This my error report is Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)'null object on**

*( private void setTotalAmount(String totalitem, String itemprice, String anterharga, String totalasemuanya))*

```
class cartTotalAmountViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView totalitems;
        private TextView totalItemprice;
        private TextView deliveryprice;
        private TextView totalharga;



        public cartTotalAmountViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            totalitems = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Total_items);
            totalItemprice=itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_price);
            deliveryprice=itemView.findViewById(R.id.delivery_price);
            totalharga=itemView.findViewById(R.id.total_semua_harga);
        }
```

```
     private void setTotalAmount(String totalitem, String itemprice, String anterharga, String totalasemuanya){

            totalitems.setText(totalitem);
            totalItemprice.setText(itemprice);
            deliveryprice.setText(anterharga);
            totalharga.setText(totalasemuanya);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using private keyword in setTotalAmount use public keyword.